# LInux restore script returning unexpected token

Tags: linux, shell, restore

I am creating a recycle bin with a restore function for linux. So far I have one script that successfully moves a file to a recycle bin however my restore script is not working.

The purpose of the restore script is to promt the user for a directory then move the selected file from the recycle bin to that directory. However when I run the script I encounter an error with "unexpected token; fi" or whatever token I try to end the file with. Can anyone see the error in my script?

```
#!/bin/bash

#Changes directory to location of recycle bin
while read -r filename
echo "Where would you like the file to be restored to?"
read newlocation

mv -i ~/recycle/$filename $newlocation
echo "File has been restored!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your while loop is wrong. In bash while loops should look like this:

```
while read -f filename ; do

    # here goes the loops body code

done
```

Notice how I added " ; do " in the loop head and how I close the loop with "done" instead of "fi".

Comment: @IzKenzie if you are using bash, you can type "help while" and it will give you a brief description of how to use the while loop.